# Multidimensional array: get second key and create first key with it

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload, multidimensional-array

UPDATE:
Thanks to Bhavik Shah, I managed to loop through it like this.

```
$file_data = array();
            foreach($files as $key => $value ){
                foreach($value as $name => $name_data ) {
                    $file_data[$name] = $files;
                }
            }
            $result = array_merge($data, $file_data);
```

---

Orgininal Question:

I'm uploading a HTML-Form, which contains text inputs and files. I then have to merge the $_POST and $_FILES arrays of to loop them through some functions (sanity checks). What I get when merging is:

```
Array
(
    [name] => A name
    [description] => A description
    [year] => 2013
    [name] => Array
        (
            [uploaded_file] => pic.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [uploaded_file] => image/jpg
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [uploaded_file] => /tmp/phpRqUUw2
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [uploaded_file] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [uploaded_file] => 1024
        )

)
```

What I actually want, is this array structure:

```
    Array
(
    [name] => A name
    [description] => A description
    [year] => 2013
    [uploaded_file] => Array (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [uploaded_file] => pic.jpg
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [uploaded_file] => image/jpg
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [uploaded_file] => /tmp/phpRqUUw2
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [uploaded_file] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [uploaded_file] => 1024
            )

    )
)
```

Since it is a variable function, I need to get the second key [uploaded_file] dynamically.

1. How do I get the second key?
2. How can I receive the needed structure?
   I played around with array_merge() and array_flip, but nothing did the job.

Thank you very much!

UPDATE:
This is the merging code:

```
$data  = isset( $_POST[ $tab ] )  ? $_POST[ $tab ]  : array();
$files = isset( $_FILES[ $tab ] ) ? $_FILES[ $tab ] : array();

$result = array_merge($data, $files);
```

Comment: show code that you used for the merging. I think, that code has to be manipulated to get the desired output.

Comment: added the merging code above.

Comment: i have submitted an answer. see if it helps you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$data  = isset( $_POST[ $tab ] )  ? $_POST[ $tab ]  : array();
$files = isset( $_FILES[ $tab ] ) ? $_FILES[ $tab ] : array();
foreach($files as $key => $value){
    $name[$key] = array($tab => $value);
}
$data[$tab] = $name;

// simply print the data of $data to get your output - just to show you
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Yes, that brought me in de right direction. I'm handling it know with two foreach loops. You can see the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just assign the $_FILES array value to a new key in a new array?

```
$files_data = array();
for (int i = 0; i < count($_POST['items']); i++) {
    // assuming each $_POST['items'] value is associated with each $_FILES value
    $item_data = $_POST['items'][i];
    $item_data['uploaded_file'] = $_FILES[i];
    $files_data[] = $item_data;
}
```